# VSCode画面分割時、エディタータブダブルクリックによるエディター拡大機能のショートカットを教えて下さい

Tags: vscode

表題の通り、VSCode画面分割時、エディターのタブをダブルクリックすると対象エディタの領域が拡大される機能についてです。非常に便利でよく利用しているのですが、ショートカットキーが存在すれば教えていただきたいです。
また、上記のようなGUI操作に対応するショートカットキーを探すいい方法があれば教えて下さい。
よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

対象エディタタブの領域が拡大される機能のショートカットキーは設定されていません。

コマンドは設定されています。
`View: Maximize Editor Group`と
`View: Reset Editor Group Sizes`です。

F1キーを押して上記のコマンドを入力後Enterキーを押すことでキーボードからフォーカスの当たっているエディタ領域を変更することができます。

もちろん<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>でコマンド一覧を表示するか`keybindigs.json`を書き換えることで、上記コマンドにショートカットキーを割り当てることができますのでご検討ください。

> GUI操作に対応するショートカットキー

ショートカットキー自体は上記のコマンド一覧で調査するのが一番確実だと思います。
GUI操作に特化した操作は、ネット上にある網羅的な記事で学習する方が手っ取り早いかもしれません。

[VSCodeでなるべくマウスを使わない開発環境をがんばる#その他の操作など](https://qiita.com/y-tsutsu/items/cfe89c0168f40a8fb353#%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9)
[【Windows版】VS Code キーボードショートカット一覧 （オススメ付き）](https://qiita.com/TakahiRoyte/items/cdab6fca64da386a690b)

> (コメントより)`View: Reset Editor Group Sizes`がkeybindings.jsonで対応するcommand

`workbench.action.evenEditorWidths`です。

**調べ方その1:**

1. コマンド一覧から対象のコマンドを右クリック(今回は`View: Reset Editor Group Sizes`)
2. コンテキストメニューから`Copy Command ID`を選択
3. コマンドIDがクリップボードにコピーされる

**調べ方その2(兼、設定のやり方):**

1. コマンド一覧から対象のコマンドをダブルクリック(今回は`View: Reset Editor Group Sizes`)
2. 任意のショートカットキーを入力(例えばCtrl + R, Ctrl + S)
3. keybindings.jsonをテキストエディタで開く([VS Code - keybindings.jsonの格納場所は？](https://infoteck-life.com/a0314-vscode-keybindings-place/))
4. 該当のキーバインドからコマンドIDを調べる

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+r ctrl+s",
        "command": "workbench.action.evenEditorWidths" 
    }
```

1. キーバインドが不要ならばコマンド一覧から対象のコマンドを選択してDelを押して削除する

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。自分では探すことができなかったので大変助かります。ちなみになんですが、`View: Reset Editor Group Sizes`がkeybindings.jsonで対応するcommandはどれでしょうか？

Comment: @Naoki 回答に追記しました。

Comment: ご丁寧に設定方法までご教授いただきありがとうございます。大変たすかりました。